# Data factory lookup (dot) in the item() name

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am having lookup wherein salesforce query is there. I am using elements (item()) in subsequent activities. Till now i had item().name or item().email but now i have item().NVMStatsSF__Related_Lead__r.FirstName which has (dot) in the field name.

How should i parse it through body tag so that it reads it correctly?

So I have the following data in item()

{
            "NVMStatsSF__Related_Lead__c": "00QE000egrtgrAK",
            "NVMStatsSF__Agent__r.Name": "ABC",
            "NVMStatsSF__Related_Lead__r.Email": "geggegg@gmail.com",
            "NVMStatsSF__Related_Lead__r.FirstName": "ABC",
            "NVMStatsSF__Related_Lead__r.OwnerId": "0025434535IIAW"
        }

now when i use item().NVMStatsSF__Agent__r.Name it will not parse because of (dot) after NVMStatsSF__Agent__r. And it is giving me the following error.

```
'item().NVMStatsSF__Related_Lead__r.Email' cannot be evaluated because property 'NVMStatsSF__Related_Lead__r' doesn't exist, available properties are 'NVMStatsSF__Related_Lead__c, NVMStatsSF__Agent__r.Name, NVMStatsSF__Related_Lead__r.Email, NVMStatsSF__Related_Lead__r.FirstName, NVMStatsSF__Related_Lead__r.OwnerId'.",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "WebActivityToAddPerson"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it worked. I was being silly.

Instead of taking the value from the child table with the help of (dot) operator I just used subquery. Silly see.

And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

this is because ADF uses '.' for object reading.
Could you find a way to rename the field name which contains '.'?

Comment: I am still searching for one :(

Comment: Finally I used subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need a built-in function to get the value of an object according to the key. Like getValue(item(), 'key.nestkey'). But unfortunately, seems there isn't such a function. You may need handle your key first.

Comment: Is there any way to change the header or pass external header after lookup?